# Show that the Wronskian of a fundamental solution set of solutions is a constant.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the Wronskian of a fundamental solution set of solutions for a L.D.E of the form:

$ a_0(x)y^{(n)} + a_2(x)y^{(n-2)} + ... + a_n(x)y = 0$,

(there is no derivative term of the order n-1) is a constant:

Consider,  $W(x) = det(\Omega(x)) = \begin{vmatrix}
y_1(x) ... y_{n-1}(x)
\\
y_1'(x) ... y_{n-1}'(x)
\\
............
\\
y_1^{n-2}(x) ... y_{n-1}^{n-2}(x)
\end{vmatrix} $.

I wanted to use some facts about the determinant to show that the Wronskian is constant, namely: any determinant of a matrix with two rows exactly the same is $0$. However, I am not sure if the row before the last row of $W(x)$ is the same as the last row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use Abel's formula. This is often derived for $n=2$ in a standard course, but, the identity is general. In particular, for
$$ a_o y^{(n)}+a_1y^{(n-1)}+ \cdots + a_n y = 0$$
we have $W(x) = C\text{exp} \left( - \int a_1/a_o dx \right)$ hence $a_1=0$ gives $W(x)=C$.

Comment: How does that show that the Wronskian is constant? Wouldn't you still have the integral of $a_{2}(x)$ which we cannot determine if it is constant without knowing what the function is?

Comment: see page 59-60 of http://www.supermath.info/DifferentialEqns.pdf for a derivation.

Comment: well, if $a_1=0$ then the exponential of $0$ is $1$.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue now. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, now, it may well be possible to derive this directly with using Abel's formula, but, I suspect the intent is just to teach you to use Abel's formula...